# Only allow letters, spaces, hyphens, and apostrophes and saves apostrophe in safe format in MariaDB php and display name with apostrophe

Tags: php, regex, preg-match, mysql-real-escape-string

I am trying this.

```
$fullname=mysqli_real_escape_string($connect,filter_var($_POST["fullname"],FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING));
```

If I enter John O'Brien

```
The variable $fullname = John O&#39;Brien
```

I have a regex as shown below which allows the apostrophe through and saves it in the format as shown below in the table in the database which is ideal.

```
John O&#39;Brien
```

The regex I am using is

```
If(!preg_match('/^[a-z .\-&#39;]+$/i', $fullname)
```

Now the above regex works to a point, it will lets numbers through, it should not. If I were to add the number 4 as an example to the end of the name as shown below this is accepted and is let through.

```
The variable $fullname = John O'Brien4
```

Saving the apostrophe in a safe format in the database is important and being able to retrieve the name from the table and display it on the webpage with the apostrophe. Perhaps there is a simpler way to approach my problem! Any help much appreciated.

Comment: Why are you doing any of this? It's not for you to decide whether someone uses a number(or any other character) in their name. The issue of apostrophes is completely bypassed with **prepared statements**, so use them. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60174/14853083)

Comment: `which is ideal`...it doesn't look ideal at all...it looks like mangling the data for no useful reason. I can't imagine why you think that HTML-encoding the apoostrophe in your database is beneficial. It's not in a HTML document at that point. And yeah, why aren't numbers allowed? You can't say for certain that nobody would spell their name like that or that they can't enter their name into _your_ site however they wish - doesn't sound like you're running a government agency requiring official names. Read this: https://www.kalzumeus.com/2010/06/17/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-names/

Comment: mysqli_real_escape_string has been obsolete for 20 years anyway, I've no idea why you're still using it. Use prepared statements and parameters to build your queries properly.

Comment: @ADyson: Is it already 20 years ago? Time goes by…

Comment: @hakre I'm talking about since it was possible to use parameterised queries  in php (i.e. basically when mysqli arrived, which I think was around 2004ish!)

Comment: Thank you ADyson. Yes I am using prepared statements and have been for many years.

Comment: `I am using prepared statements and have been for many years`...in that case you shouldn't also be using `mysqli_real_escape_string` - that makes no sense....as I mentioned, it was made obsolete by the introduction of parameterised queries.

Comment: Thanks ADyson Yes you probably know more about it than I do. I am just trying to validate my inputs. perhaps there are more modern and contemporary ways of doing this today. I am working on a small project myself at the moment. I am not doing anything major. Do you know what the modern substitute for mysqli_real_escape_string is if any? Thanking you in advance.

Comment: It depends what you mean by "validate" exactly? What precisely are you trying to achieve. Mysqli_real_escape_string was never a validation function to begin with. If you parameterise your queries then you simply don't need it - the parameterization is the substitute for that

Comment: And the rest of what you're doing (in terms of seemingly placing arbitrary restrictions on the contents of a name) also doesn't really make any sense, as I think we've already covered in the earlier comments

Comment: I remember about 10 years ago working with a MS Access table. I remember allowing an apostrophe directly into a field in the table. Well, it caused havoc when I tried to run a SQL statement on the table from PHP. The table in question was acting as a lookup table with a few names in it. When I put in John O'Brien into the table the problems happened.

Comment: From that day on I perhaps learned that you can't allow apostrophes directly into a field in a table. Now maybe you can't with MS Access. Now in relation to prepared statements I reconfigured my code above to allow the apostrophe directly into the table in MariaDB. Now haven looked at the field after insertion I could see the apostrophe was unformatted in any way. Does an unformatted apostrophe in a field in a table cause problems. Again the apostrophe above was inserted into the table field via a prepared statement in php. Any assistance much appreciated Adyson.

Comment: @David: A string in a database field can contain every character (or empty, NULL) that is available for that field, which is merely the allowed character set. Let's say you have binary, then every binary. The placeholders in a prepared statement (parameterized query) make this easy as you have variables on the one hand and the query on the other. If the whole SQL query is build from strings, the proper encoding of each part needs to be done as otherwise the resulting SQL query is not the SQL you intended. This is often harder to do correct, therefore also parameterized queries win again.

Comment: @David: To add: There _should_ be a Q&A on site which answers your concrete question,  otherwise try to give this question the dedicated, specific context and example it becomes clearly answerable. It's also not wrong to answer a question in the end on ones own, so you have question and answer both written by yourself. Then you can have it on site for later and continue to edit it as times change.

Comment: You didn't say exactly what "havoc" was casued by this apostrophe in Access but I'd bet 99.9% it was because of whatever code was trying to read or process that data in an incorrect way, and nothing to do with the simple fact of storing it there. Every database in the world allows apostrophes. You really think that after 50+ years of the existence of relational databases that nobody has figured out how to store a simple apostrophe without needing to mangle it first?? It sounds like an XY problem, where you dont' know how to do X so you try to do Y (which is always something weird) instead.

Comment: `Does an unformatted apostrophe in a field in a table cause problems`...simple answer: No.